# Why am I still getting a Slack error for operation_timeout even though I've sent an acknowledgement?

Tags: javascript, timeout, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I'm working on a Slack bot which is handling a lot of api calls. Through the slash command, I keep getting the error `failed with the error "operation_timeout"`.

I thought the issue would be resolved if I sent a response back to Slack using the response_url it sends to us in the body. However even though I'm sending a response back to Slack right away I'm still getting the timeout error?

```
const doSomething = async (body) => {
    await axios.post(
        body.response_url,
        {
            text: "Handling the slash command",
        },
        {
            headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
        }
    );

    // rest of the code
    // multiple api calls, etc.
}
```

I'm receiving the `"Handling the slash command"` in Slack as an ephemeral message. But unfortunately the `failed with the error "operation_timeout"` error also pops up right afterwards.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You need to respond immediately with a HTTP 204 NoContent type response to server as an acknowledgement. You can then later push data to the response_url to do more actions with the workflow.